# How do I get rid of whitespace when rendering without touching template indentations?

Tags: templating, datetime, whitespace

I have the following code.

```
{% spaceless %}
{% for date in entry.d_date %}
    {% if date.showMonth == 1 %}
    {{ date.date.month }}-
    {% endif %}
    {% if date.showDate == 1 %}
    {{ date.date.day }}-
    {% endif %}
    {{ date.date.year }}
{% endfor %}
{% endspaceless %}
```

Which outputs 1- 1- 2014

Is there anyway to get rid of the whitespace without touching the indentation? I've used `{spaceless}` but it's not working.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [spaceless](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#whitespace-control) tag only removes whitespace between HTML tags. You have to use the [whitespace control modifier](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#whitespace-control) on your tags to remove leading and or trailing whitespace.

Additionally I'd use the [ternary operator](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#other-operators) for your conditionals (and put the hyphen inside it):

```
{% for date in entry.d_date %}
    {{  date.showMonth == 1 ? date.date.month ~ '-' : '' -}}
    {{- date.showDate == 1 ? date.date.day ~ '-' : '' -}}
    {{- date.date.year }}
{% endfor %}
```